Format datetime in polars
I have a polars dataframe that contains a datetime column. I want to convert this column to strings in the format %Y%m. For example, all dates in January 2024 should be converted to "202401".
from datetime import datetime

import polars as pl


data = {
    "ID" : [1,2,3],
    "dates" : [datetime(2024,1,2),datetime(2024,1,3),datetime(2024,1,4)],
}

df = pl.DataFrame(data)

I have tried using strftime. However, the following AttributeError is raised.
AttributeError: 'Expr' object has no attribute 'strftime'


.dt.to_string() is also a more "user friendly" alias for strftime.

Note that pl.Expr.dt.strftime is available under the pl.Expr.dt namespace. Hence, it is called on the dt attribute of an expression and not the expression directly.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("dates").dt.strftime("%Y%m")
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬────────┐
│ ID  ┆ dates  │
│ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ str    │
╞═════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 202401 │
│ 2   ┆ 202401 │
│ 3   ┆ 202401 │
└─────┴────────┘


you can use strftime like this:
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("dates").dt.strftime("%Y%m"))

print(df)
┌─────┬────────┐
│ ID  ┆ dates  │
│ --- ┆ ---    │
│ i64 ┆ str    │
╞═════╪════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 202401 │
│ 2   ┆ 202401 │
│ 3   ┆ 202401 │
└─────┴────────┘

